# LWJGL random lines inbenween shapes

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have random lines inbetween my quads in my game which I would like to remove:[image]

as you can see, there appear to be lines inbetween the cubes. Does anyone know how to remove them? I am using openGL.

Edit:
 What I mean is is there any OpenGL functions such as glEnable to fix this?

Comment: What should we do only with the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have all of your textures on on image?

Near the edge of the block, OpenGL is sampling nearby pixels to make it smooth, so on the edge of your dirt block you can see it slightly fading into a stone block

try the lwjgl version of this:

`glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)`
`glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)`

(the above is in in c++)

This will give you the pixelated effect like minecraft

Take a look at this for some more info http://gregs-blog.com/2008/01/17/opengl-texture-filter-parameters-explained/

Comment: This fixed it and I realized that my depth func was set to GL_LESS so I changed it to GL_LEQUAL and now the grass sides show!